# How do I update my web app features in the linux server? web app is build with Python, Flask, uwsgi and server nginx

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I am new to Python development. I am building a test Python app and already deployed into a web server and accessing it through public IP. Now I have updated the source(that is added some more models and templates), Now I want my public IP under port 80 should show updated code.

How do I do this?

Comment: In short I am trying to explain, how do I rebuild my web application or website run through Python, Flask and uwsgi in port 80. I have updated my files and it is not reflecting through public IP. localhost is working fine with port 5000. production server is not showing the changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used any sort of `version control`, it's just `commit` and `push`/`pull` to the server.

if not, you have to copy the code, paste it in the server, restart the application and it work's with new code.

best approach is make a `service`, `deploy` the code with `git` version control, run the `service` and you are good to go. service will start automatically in case of system-restart and such.

Comment: I have deployed Github in the server and my codes updated to my application. i have verified that. I am new to Python Development. How do I restart the application and how do I make service.

Comment: you should provide more information on how you did it. so you have sent your new code to the server? what have you used to run flask? `Gunicorn`? `uwsgi`? give us more information please